# Cannot install pyvisa in virtualenv due to setuptools error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

I have Python running in a virtualenv and checked pip and setuptools. Installed as follows:

```
(venv)root ~/Desktop/virtualenv # pip list
pip (6.0.8)
setuptools (14.3.1)
```

Then tried to install pyvisa and encountered a setuptools error

```
(venv)root ~/Desktop/virtualenv # pip install -U pyvisa
Collecting pyvisa
  Using cached PyVISA-1.6.3.zip
  setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
```

I tried to install the local package and had similar error:

```
(venv)root ~/Desktop/virtualenv/pyvisa-master # python setup.py install
Please install or upgrade setuptools or pip to continue
```

Here's my Python and Linux (64-bit CentOS) environment:

```
(venv)root ~/Desktop/virtualenv # python -V
Python 2.7.9
(venv)root ~/Desktop/virtualenv # uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:55:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The main Python environment (v2.6.6) had not such issue. But cannot use it due to architecture conflict with NI-VISA (64 vs 32-bit). I’ve been stuck here for a while and cannot find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where `pip list` showed setuptools as installed but when I tried to `pip install` anything I got the `"setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution"` error. I was able to resolve it by adding `sudo` and `pip install`ing as root. Maybe that will work for you?

Edit:
Actually, this might not work. It looks like when I `sudo pip install` the packages can't be accessed by non root users. I just ran a `pip list` and my packages aren't there but a `sudo pip list` shows them. Now I'm lost.